# How to add text between double quotes i.e. "word" on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to export an ssrs report to csv and when I open it on notepad ++ or notepad each column text needs to be between double quotes , for example "word1"

1- I've tried to change the csv render format to FTP-8 but the words did not have the double quotes at the beginning or end.

2- I've tried to use char function on ssrs expression: 
`= chr(34) &  Fields!Location.Value & chr (34)`  .. Instead of getting the desired result "word1" I'm getting  """word1"""

I did this change on reporting services:

```
<Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
            <Configuration>
            <DeviceInfo>
            <NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
            <FieldDelimiter></FieldDelimiter>
            <ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode>
            <Qualifier></Qualifier>
            <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
            </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```

I did this other change on SSRS expression

```
= chr(34) &  Fields!Location.Value & chr (34)
```

Desired output
[image]

Results I'm getting (I've not put the ssrs expression on column 2 since column 1 is not showing correct results):

[image]

Please help

Comment: Why would you need an output with quotes in a .csv file? This is not should never be done. What do you do with the .csv file after? If you use the file for further analisys add the quotes at in the last step (user view). Also `chr(34)` and `"""` is the same, both represent one quote `chr(34) = "` and `""" = "` and in the textfile the second is used

Comment: @Strawberryshrub the csv file will be uploaded to another system that requires all words between double quotes , I understand that chr(34) is equal to " and """ but do not need 3 double quotes at the end of the word , just 1